# Test Nuget Auth Credentials with `dotnet` in Docker Image

Tags: .net, docker, nuget

I'm looking for a safe and straightforward way to fail my image build if the supplied credentials are invalid. The issue is that the repo I need to pull the packages from has a policy which locks the account after too many failed attempts -- and since each individual package counts as a separate authentication attempt, one bad build attempt will lock the account.

In my `Dockerfile` I set up the nuget source like so, and then restore (or publish/run, etc.) like so.

```
RUN dotnet nuget add source https://my-example-repo.jfrog.io/my-example/api/nuget/nuget  \
    -n Artifactory \
    -u ${JFROG_USERNAME} \
    -p ${JFROG_PASSWORD} \
    --store-password-in-clear-text
RUN dotnet restore
```

The ideal solution would be one of two things:

1. A flag for `dotnet restore` that exits immediately with non-zero code if the any package fails to restore, e.g. `dotnet restore --failfast`
2. A single, safe, idempotent command to authenticate with the current credentials and exit non-zero if the credentials don't work.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that. Probably, you can create a simple CLI util that programmatically checks the credentials and fails with exit code if they are invalid. Why do you have invalid credentials? Usually, you set them and they are fine.

Comment: i don't know why I have valid credentials, that's why I want to be able to test them. This is your typical enterprise scenario -- one team owns the repository, another team owns the build environment, and here I am trying to get them to connect without constantly having to involve everyone.

Comment: What about just creating a test project that only references one of the packages?

Answer (score 1):

> It looks a bit hacky but I suggest such an approach.

You can simply create a test C# project with one reference to the package from your private repository.

Then you try to restore it by the `dotnet` CLI.

If your credentials are invalid, it will fail, there will be a non-zero exit code.

---

0. Configure your NuGet source with credentials

As you know, when you run `dotnet restore`, it uses a special mechanism to accumulate settings from different levels:

- Solution
- User
- Computer

> [Microsoft Docs / Common NuGet configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior)

So, when you run this command, your user `nuget.config` file is updated.

(On Windows it is located there `%APPDATA%\NuGet\nuget.config`)

```sh
dotnet nuget add source https://my-example-repo.jfrog.io/my-example/api/nuget/nuget  \
    -n Artifactory \
    -u ${JFROG_USERNAME} \
    -p ${JFROG_PASSWORD} \
    --store-password-in-clear-text
```

1. Create a test project file with name `credentials-test.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Replace an example by your package from private repository. -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.GitHub" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

2. Then simply run a `dotnet restore` command:

```
dotnet restore .\credentials-test.csproj
```

In case of valid credentials, the result in PowerShell will be:

```
> dotnet restore .\credentials-test.csproj
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored C:\Projects\nuget-restore-2\credentials-test.csproj (in 340 ms).
> $LastExitCode
0
```

In case of invalid credentials or any other failure, the result will be:

```
> dotnet restore .\credentials-test.csproj
  Determining projects to restore...
<SOME ERROR MESSAGE>
> $LastExitCode
1 <-- Or some different non-zero exit code
```

Doesn't look very nice. But works.

---

Just for fun, I spent some time implementing a .NET CLI Tool to provide you a CLI command for that. However, it's worse than the idea that is described above.

You can check it out here:
https://youtu.be/SanQAVAZM2o